# Creating a Xenserver 6.2 pool

Tags: xenserver

I would appreciate a bit of guidance with the following task.

I have a standalone Xenserver 6.2 that is running 2 Windows 2012 VMs. This server is connected via NFS to a NAS server.

I recently bought 2 new servers as well as another NAS server and want to create a pool of 3 to take advantage of HA etc.

Unfortunately the CPUs are not similar enough so Xencenter suggests I can add them to a pool but with the older server as master.

What would be the safest way to do this without affecting the existing VMs?

Essentially I'm unaware as to what Xencenter does when you create a pool and how it affects existing VMs and connected storage.

Would it be better to create a pool with the 2 new servers and migrate the VMs there?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, what you do have now is a server running in Xenserver but with no pool configured.

Which of the servers are you setting up as master? I guess one of the new.

Setting the server you already have as a server wouldn't affect your vms. If you manage to join to the pool the other servers as slaves and then adding the new NAS to the pool you're done.

More information you can find in the Citrix XenServer ® 6.2.0 Administrator's Guide

http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/34969-102-704897/reference.pdf